# How to use if else with range in python?

Tags: python

Expected:
If Cost is 0-1000 print Saver else 1001-10000 print Economy else above 10000 print Flexi.

My Code:

```
if int(number) in range(1, 1000):
    print "Saver"
elif int(number) in range(1001, 10000):
    print "Economy"
else:
    print "Flexi"
```

I also used the code:

```
if ( var >= 0) and (var < 1001) : print "Saver" else
if ( var >= 1001) and (var < 10001) : print "Economy" else
if ( var >= 10001) : print "Flexi";
```

But both throw the below sytax errors

```
 File "cargo.py", line 1                                                       
    if ( var >= 0) and (var < 1001) : print "Saver" else                        
                                                  ^                             
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3+ the arguments to `print` must be in `()` e.g. `print("Saver")`

Comment: What syntax error? If you're using python 3 then you need brackets for `print` but you haven't told us the error

Comment: what is the error you are getting? That would be more useful to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: Be careful about `range(a, b)`, 1000 is neither in `range(1, 1000)`, nor in `range(1001, 10000)` and will hence print `"Flexi"`...

Comment: I added syntax error also in question. But Alfie Torres answer (code) working for me.

Comment: Under basically no circumstances will a syntax error be a useful, on-topic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this uses the new version of python. Also note that range() is not inclusive so if you want to have all the values in between such as range you need to add one to your boundaries.

```
print ("Enter a number :")
number = input()

if int(number) in range(0, 1001):
    print("Saver")
elif int(number) in range(1001, 10001):
    print("Economy")
else:
    print("Flexi")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the print command is missing parentheses

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, parenthesis is missing for print()
Notice that `1000` is not included in both the range. `range(1,1000)` is exclusive of 1000.

```
if int(number) in range(1, 1000):
    print("Saver")
elif int(number) in range(1001, 10000):
    print ("Economy")
else:
    print ("Flexi")
```